Why do we have both the word "three" and the numeral "3" in this sentence?
Why do we have both the word "three" and the numeral "3" in this sentence?

The number 345 has three digits, where the first digit is a 3.


Because....it's a digit. The word three is not a digit.

The number 345 does not have 3 digits. It has 3, 4 and 5 digits. The use of 'three' disambiguates. Another example is "four 4-legged animals", used to make the phrase readable.

PLEASE stop using the [tag:grammar] tag for things that have nothing whatsoever to do with English grammar. I've told you this before, too.

Why is this tagged "style-manuals"? The question doesn't bring them up. It is true that many style manuals will dictate a point below which numbers should be spelled out and above which they should be given numerically, but that has nothing to do with this excerpt, which couldn't very well spell out even "three hundred fourty-five" without missing its own point.

Because 'The number 345 has 3 digits, where the first digit is a 3' uses '3' in two roles, which is confusing.

Ah-ha! I found it: numerals as numerals (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/numbers/numerals). That's how they say it in that guide; short and simple.

You should give the source for any quote, so we can tell what the context is and know that you've not just made it up or it's not a mistake or AI-generated. Also you should explain what your question is, why you're asking, and what research you've done.

Because there we are talking about literal verbatim symbols 345 and 3 written out as numerals, not about three whatevers, which is different.
Depending on the context, that might have been more clearly typeset in any of these fashions:

The number 345 has three digits, where the first digit is a 3.
The number “345” has three digits, where the first digit is a “3”.
The number 345 has three digits, where the first digit is a 3.

I leave as an exercise for the reader to decide whether mentions of the word number in this sentence should or could be better written saying numeral instead.

This was already adequately addressed in your other post. To summarise: Whether in mathematical writing or newsprint,

Texts read better when sentences don't start with numerals or notation.
For natural numbers smaller than 10,

it's sometimes better to write them as numerals: The number 2 is the only even prime is better than The number two is the only even prime (here, '2' is a mathematical object of interest);
it's sometimes better to spell them out: This equation has two solutions: 5 and 7 is better than This equation has 2 solutions: 5 and 7 or This equation has two solutions: five and seven (here, the count 'two' is being distinguished from the mathematical objects of interest '5' and '7');
sometimes it doesn't matter: a function of two variables and a function of 2 variables are both fine, unless the house style guide specifically prescribes the former.



As an example, consider this post, where the number 3 was deliberately spelt out in the second paragraph, and deliberately written as a numeral in the third paragraph.
